# Unable to locate package phpmyadmin on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ppa, phpmyadmin

Whenever I try to install phpmyadmin on my ubuntu server 18.04 I get the following errors

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package php-gettext
```

Most threads I ca find suggest reupdating and upgrading using apt, but doing so doesn't do anything, also I get that error on the fourth line

```
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: please check your sources.list file and change from Release to InRelease.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I had the same problem but installing xrdp,  your solutions works great with this issue too

Comment: This worked best for me to get phpmyadmin installed. Would recommend as the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your ppa doesn't serve phpmyadmin for bionic version. You should remove ppa first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt update
```

then run your command again

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

Comment: Still same issue, unable to locate it

Comment: have you try `sudo apt dist-upgrade` when upgrading?

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got a "The user named '~nijel' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/phpmyadmin'" - I had to manually remove the reference file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nijel-ubuntu-phpmyadmin-xenial.list

Comment: Check your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and remove the file for phpmyadmin

Comment: you write `sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext` <-- I think now with Ubuntu 20.4     you just need `sudo apt install phpmyadmin`.  'cos php-gettext equivalent is installed with  php. And  php-mbstring is installed with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score -2):

I have precisely the same issue. Tried sudo apt install phpmyadmin (with and without php-gettext and php-mbstring which I installed separately as I am using php7.1) but always *get E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin*

and for the add-add-repository

*E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu bionic Relea                        se' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                        bled by default.*

Also tried downloading the package from a mirror but got nowhere with that either.

Is the ppa broken and is there another solution or workaround or something I can do to help resolve this issue?

Comment: Please ask your own question